# line graph not showing in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, graph

I have a component that defines a line graph, following the online example, but nothing shows on my page. for reference, the commented bar graph shows if every other graph is commented out. I don't understand why the bar graph can be shown but not the line graph. I don't think this is an version issue since the bar graph can be shown.
Any idea?

linegraph.vue:

```
<template>
    <Line id="lg2"
    :data="graphdata"
    />
    <p>line graph</p>
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
name: 'LineChart',
components: { Line },
data() {
    return {
        labels: ['v','r','g','d','s','w','y'],
        graphdata: {
            datasets: [{
            label: 'My First Dataset',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            tension: 0.1
        }],
       }
     }
   }
}  

      
</script>

<style>

#lg1 {
    color: blueviolet;
}
</style>
```

app.vue:

```
<template>
   <HeaderPart></HeaderPart>
   <div class="columns">
   <div class="column is-4"><p>1a</p></div>
   <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
   <div class="column is-4"><p>2a</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    First column
    <p>json:</p>
    <ReadData />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Second column
    <LineChart/>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Third column
    <LineChart/>
  <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components -->
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Fourth column
    <MoneyGraph xr="x1"/>
    <MoneyGraph y="y"/>
    <TestOne tmsg="4:e"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
<div class="column is-10">
  <p>columns 10</p>

</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import HeaderPart from './components/HeaderPart.vue'
import MoneyGraph from './components/MoneyGraph.vue'
import TestOne from './components/TestOne.vue'
//import BarChart from './components/BarChart.vue'
import ReadData from './components/ReadData.vue'
//import ScatterGraph from './components/ScatterGraph.vue'
import LineChart from './components/lineGraph.vue'
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    HeaderPart,
    MoneyGraph,
    TestOne,
  //  BarChart,
    ReadData,
    LineChart
} 
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you not get any errors in your console?  Running your code I get an error about unregistered elements. Checking your import statement the answer becomes clear.  Importing `BarElement` for a line chart doesn't make sense.  Line charts have their own required elements that need to be imported and registered.  You need `PointElement` and `LineElement`.  The vue-chartjs [example](https://vue-chartjs.org/examples/) for a line chart also shows this.

Comment: ok, I changed the imports and followed the provided example, and now I can see a graph. thanks.